# Fancytree Drag and Drop - how to disable the whole tree from scrolling up when clicked on

Tags: jquery, css, fancytree

The Fancytree drag and drop demo example has the problem too. To replicate the problem:

1. Visit the Fancytree DnD demo example here: http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/#sample-ext-dnd.html.
2. Make the browser small enough so the tree in the page doesn't fit in its entirety.
3. When clicking on a node in the tree, the tree's container automatically scrolls up so its top is at the top of the page.

This is particularly a UX problem when I want to double-click on a node because the first click makes the tree jump so the second click goes somewhere unintended.

Any ideas how to overcome this?

I tried these ideas but none worked:

- Setting the tree's `focusOnClick` to false
- Setting the tree's `autoScroll` to false
- Change `position: relative` to `inherit` everywhere in the css
- Setting the following dnd properties:

  ```
  dnd: {
    draggable: {
      zIndex: 1000,
      scroll: false,
      containment: "parent",
     revert: "invalid"
    },
   focusOnClick: false
  }
  ```

Comment: I tested the scenario described above on three different browsers (Chrome v. 48.0.2564, Safari 9.0.1, Firefox 43.0.4) on Mac OS X El Capitan and the problem doesn't happen on Firefox but does happen on the other two browsers.

Comment: Thanks to feedback from fancytree's developer, Martin Wendt, this seems to be an issue (perhaps a bug) with jQueryUI library: https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/14940

Comment: This query has been answered here: https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/issues/577